# Is there too much "backtracking" in item "Regular Expressions"?

Tags: discussion, documentation

The documentation list for [Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics) has two blocks for "Backtracking" (see [977](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/977/backtracking) and [1608](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1608/backtracking)). Splitting one topic into two sections seems likely to confuse. Should the two be combined?

If they should be combined then that also leads to asking why were two identically named sections created and can (or should) that be prevented in the future?

Comment: This has already been [proposed as an improvement by nhahtdh](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1608/backtracking), about 13 minutes before your question was posted.